# Mount image only for active user

Tags: mount, dmg

I have an encrypted dmg with private files. When I mount it I see is as drive but when another person opens their users they see the unit available too which I don't want.

I even tried changing the permission for that other users to write only so they can't see the content but they still do.

Is there a way to mount an encrypted image and have it available only to the user that mount it?

Comment: To clarify -  on a single Mac, you have a DMG disk image open on your Desktop, and with Fast User Switching, other user(s) login and see the open disk image on their Desktops. Mounted disk images are special volumes which don’t really accept permissions and ownership changes. They are usually mounted with “Ignore ownership on this volume set. I’d just dismount the DMG before going to the login screen. Or just log out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the other user does not have administrative privileges.

You can prevent the other user from viewing the files by entering a command to change permissions. For example, if the volume name is `MyVolume`, then enter the command given below.

```
chmod 700 /Volumes/MyVolume
```

If you have administrative privileges, the you can change the permissions from the Get Info window for the volume `MyVolume`. The steps are given below.

1. Open the Get Info window for volume `MyVolume`. Note: If this Get Info window loses focus, you may have to start over.
2. Unlock by clicking on the lock shown at the bottom of the window. You will be asked for your password.
3. Under Sharing & Permissions, change "everyone" to "No access".
4. Under Sharing & Permissions, delete "staff".
5. Lock by clicking on the lock shown at the bottom of the window.

To revert back to the default permissions, enter the command given below.

```
 chmod 775 /Volumes/MyVolume
```